# Build Xcode project from command line that use OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension

Tags: ios, xcode, sonarqube

I am trying to build an Ios app with Objective-C xcode project
The project is using OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension that is why I am specifying the architecture.

the command:

```
xcodebuild ARCHS=armv6,armv7 ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO build
```

but the compilation fails and It throws an error:

```
Exiting because upload-symbols was run in validation mode
```

The reason I am doing this is because I need to use the sonarqube wrapper and it takes the build command as argument:

```
sonar-wrapper --out-dir=bw-output <<build command>>
```

but I am only able to build the xcode project using xcode

If there is a better way to integrate sonarqube to this kind of projects let me know please.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using Fastlane instead of using the xcodebuild CLI directly, I find Fastlane is much more user friendly. I use it for my CI/CD deployments.

It looks like there is some Sonarqube integration as well:
https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/sonar/

Website: https://fastlane.tools

Answer (score 0):

I successfully built the project specifying the debug mode, workspace and scheme like this:

```
xcodebuild -configuration Debug -workspace <<workspace>> -scheme <<scheme>> clean build
```